# Create-or-return-cached object

Tags: c#, caching, design-patterns

I find myself writing a lot of code like this:

```
private Foo _CacheFoo;

public Foo GetFoo() {
  if (this._CacheFoo == null) {
    this._CacheFoo = new Foo();
  }
  return this.CacheFoo;
}

private Bar _CacheBar;

public Bar GetBar() {
  if (this._CacheBar == null) {
    this._CacheBar = new Bar();
  }
  return this._CacheBar;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a sensible way to encapsulate the caching part of that.

Comment: Using local members for caching? I've never had to abstract that, however I do use the null coalescing operator a lot for this style: `return _CacheFoo ?? (_CacheFoo = new Foo());`. For caching using a cache provider, I've used expressions in the past to take the method to call as an expression, which in turn powers getting the cache key (via arguments), and amending method parameters (via expression visitors).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private Lazy<Foo> _foo = new Lazy<Foo>(() => new Foo());
public Foo GetFoo()
{
    return _foo.Value;
}
```

Though that still is relatively a lot to type per instance you want to return.

Comment: Can't believe I completely forgot about `Lazy<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use some syntactic sugar, it slightly reduces amount of code:

```
private Foo _CacheFoo;
public Foo GetFoo()
{
    return _CacheFoo ?? (_CacheFoo = new Foo());
}
```